# Tomcat connection pooling, install jdbc driver for web-app

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, connection-pooling

I am making a web-app with **Tomcat 6** as the container and I'm trying to use connection pooling. The jdbc driver I am using is **jtds-1.2.2**.
The pool works fine when the driver jar is placed under `${Catalina_Home}/lib`, but my hosting provider would not let me do so.

I get a CNF-Exception when the driver is placed in the `WEB-INF/lib`.

Could someone please provide a solution where I won't have to access the tomcat installation?

Comment: Does it crib for net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver or some other class?

Comment: yes actually. The exception says that Class net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver was not found.

Comment: and the Resource entry in server.xml?

Comment: no, can't use server.xml for the same reason I can't place anything under tomcat's /lib.
The Resource entry is in /META-INF/context.xml

Comment: I wanted to accept both, Pascal's and BalusC's, answers as both answered appropriately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't have control over the server, then you're lost. Just create the connection pool yourself instead of letting the container do it.

I suggest to use [c3p0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/) for this (which is far better than Tomcat's builtin DBCP since it's locked to a single thread). Put the c3p0 libraries in the `/WEB-INF/lib` and create it as per [its documentation](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html):

```
ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource(); 
dataSource.setDriverClass("org.postgresql.Driver"); 
dataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/testdb");
dataSource.setUser("dbuser");
dataSource.setPassword("dbpassword"); 
// ...

Connection connection = null;
// ...
try {
    connection = dataSource.getConnection();
    // ...
} finally {
    // ...
    if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {} // Always close resources in finally!
}
```

Comment: Good, then I should go for c3p0 :). Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

To use Tomcat's connection pool, you **must** copy the JDBC Driver's jar into `$CATALINA_HOME/lib` (as [documented](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html)) so that the driver class is visible through the [*Common class loader*](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html) or DBCP won't be able to find it, hence the `ClassNotFoundException`. Tomcat's class loaders hierarchy is illustrated below:

```
      Bootstrap
          |
       System
          |
       Common
       /     \
  Webapp1   Webapp2 ...
```

And libraries from `WEB-INF/lib` are not visible from the *Common class loader* (which is a good thing).

If you can't copy your driver into `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`, you won't be able to use Tomcat's connection pool. In that case, you'll have to use a standalone connection pool (and to bundle it along your driver in `WEB-INF/lib`). And I second [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873510/tomcat-connection-pooling-install-jdbc-driver-for-web-app/2875482#2875482) here, I would use C3P0.