# Use jdbc connection in a web application (jsp, Tomcat and MySQL)

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, tomcat, jdbc

I have a problem when I try to make database calls from a web application.

I'm using a javabean to make these calls. 
I have already tested this bean, and it is working in classical application (i mean: not a web application).

I tried to use it in a jsp pages, but it didn't work. I got an exception:

```
>java.sql.SQLException
No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_hafic?relaxAutoCommit=true
```

I read articles about how to make database calls from within tomcat environment, but I'm still quite lost.

I'm using jsp/tomcat/mysql.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873510/tomcat-connection-pooling-install-jdbc-driver-for-web-app

Answer (score 3):

First read the [documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/UsingDataSources):

> Install the .jar file(s) containing the JDBC driver in Tomcat's
>   common/lib folder. You do not need to put them in your application's
>   WEB-INF/lib folder. When working with J2EE DataSources, the web
>   application server manages connections for your application.

Answer (score 0):

3 common problems:

1. Incorrect syntax `Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/XX","root","XXXX")`
2. Typo mistake on `"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"`
   e.g. `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();`
3. Missing `mysql_jdbc` Jar
   Include the latest mysql jdbc driver in your tomecat classpath

your situation should be the problem 3, download the driver at http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

add the library at `WEB-INF/lib/` and deploy again.

Hope it can help!